# Ruby 2.3.1 syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby

I cannot seem to get to the bottom of this error.

This is my code:

```
if data_header_seen && ss_line.start_with? ('Sample_ID,')
  data_section.push(ss_line)
end
```

and this is my error message in its entirety:

```
syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
        if data_header_seen && ss_line.start_with? ('Sample_ID,')
```

Comment: Did you instantiate `data_header_seen`?

Comment: It's a `SyntaxError`. The values are completely and utterly irrelevant, since the code doesn't even parse, let alone run.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Ruby reads your code as:

```
if (data_header_seen && ss_line.start_with?) ('Sample_ID,')
# ...
```

Just remove the space between the method call and its argument:

```
if data_header_seen && ss_line.start_with?('Sample_ID,')
  data_section.push(ss_line)
end
```